# Browser doesn't apply client certificate: 403.7

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, authentication

I'm trying to set up client certificate authentication. I was able to generate a CA-, server- and client-certificate. As long as I use Fiddler everything works as expected. However, as soon as I start using a browser it doesn't work anymore (HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden).

Of course I imported the client certificate in the Personal store and I made sure Client Certificate Negotiation is enabled.

I also tried `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -state -debug` but I couldn't really make sense of the result... The only thing what's weird is that my CA doesn't show up in the `Acceptable client certificate CA names` section.

Anything else I could try?

**Update:**
I think it doesn't matter but my server certificate is set up for 127.0.0.1. Therefore I'm using `https://127.0.0.1/...` in my browsers.

**Update2:**
Using Wireshark I noticed that my servers' response depends on the client:

Fiddler (OK):

```
Client Hello 
Server Hello, Certificate, Server Hello Done
```

Browser (Not OK):

```
Client Hello
Server Hello, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
```

**Update3:**
After enabling `clientcertnegotiation` the server response is different but still doesn't work:

```
Server Hello, Certificate
Certificate Request
Certificate, Client Key Exchange, Change Cipher Spec, Encrypted Handshake Message
```

My self-signed CA doesn't seem to be in the Distinguished Names list...

**Update4:**
SSL Settings: Checked `Require SSL` and Client certificates set as `Required`. Client cert shows up in Personal and the intended purpose is Client Authentication.

Comment: "Browser" in update 2 is a session resumption; this browser was connected to this server before your wireshark capture. Restart the browser to get a full handshake. Update 3 should have ServerHelloDone after the CertRequest, did you omit it? You say openssl s_client didn't show your CA in "Acceptable client CA"; did that show some other CAs or no CAs? If server specifies an empty preference list the client e.g. browser can and should use whatever key/cert it wants. ...

Comment: ... If server gives a preference list not including your CA, browsers typically will not authenticate, as you apparently got, although to confirm check the client Cert message (the second one), does it contain no certs? In that case you must change, or remove, the server's preference. What's the server?

Comment: Too slow to edit, but I didn't notice you had accepted pepo's assumption server is IIS so see possible answer.

Comment: I didn't omit ServerHelloDone. It did't show up... Yes, CA-list is NOT empty but my CA is not in. The client does NOT contain a cert (`Certificates Length: 0`). Server is Win 7, IIS 7.5.

Comment: Looks like Fiddler sends cert even if CA not in list but IE needs to get a list with CA... If that's the case: how do I get my CA in the list???

Comment: Sorry, my bad, you'd already covered that one too. I give up.

Comment: To be more specific, AFAICT putting the root in LocalComputer TrustedRoot should have gotten it in the client-CA list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the issue and a workaround:

As mentioned in Update3, `Distinguished Names` doesn't contain my CA. This is because `Distinguished Names` has a limit of 2^14 bytes (16384 bytes). Because I do have a lot of CA installed on my machine my CA simply didn't make it in. The TLS standard would allow to send multiple messages but unfortunately Windows doesn't support this!

As mentioned [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/933430) you have a few possibilities. The simplest one is this:

At your server add a `DWORD` (not `QWORD`!) value called `SendTrustedIssuerList` in your registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL` and set it to `0`. This will prevent your server from sending a list at all, letting the client choose from any installed client certificate.

Unfortunately I couldn't see any traces in the Event Viewer (as reported elsewhere). Therefore the issue wasn't easy to spot (I had to use Wireshark in order to check `Distinguished Names`).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Accept option instead of the Require option of the "Client certificates" feature.

1. In IIS Manager, locate the Web application for which you want to change the SSL setting.
2. In Features View, double-click SSL Settings.
3. On the SSL Settings page, **select the Accept option under Client certificates**.
4. In the Actions pane, click Apply.

[More info here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/942067/-http-error-403-7---forbidden-error-when-you-run-a-web-application-tha)

Answer (score 0):

**Client certificate** should be imported in **CurrentUser\My** store with private key (i.e. p12 or pfx file usually).
**CA certificate** should be in **LocalMachine\Root** store so that IIS trusts all certificates issued by the CA and the CA is trusted for every user on the computer.

**CRL issued by the CA** should be either **available through URL** (specified in every end entity certificate that CA issued) or imported in **LocalMachine\My** store.

NOTE: openssl doesn't use windows certificate store so this will have no efect on `openssl s_client -connect 127.0.0.1:443 -state`

Comment: I think I've done this: I can see my Client Certificate in Current User Personal Certificates, my Server Certificate in Local Computer Personal Certificates and my CA in Local Computer Trusted Root Certification Authorities Certificates...
For server and client certificates I've used pfx files.

Comment: What about CRL? Do you have any? IIS validates client certificate by checking revocation information.

Comment: I enabled/disabled "Verify Client Certification Revocation". It doesn't work in neither case...

Comment: Try network capture in IE and look where the request is going. Maybe something from Fiddler is still configured and your request doesn't go dirrectly to IIS.

Comment: Hm, could you add IIS SSL settings? I tried to change mine to require SSL (checkbox) and Require client certificate (radio). After that I did get 403.7 when I did not select client certificate to connect with. You do have client certificate in your user store with clientAuth extension, right?

Comment: And does the browser show a dialogue with certificate selection? If you have only one certificate in store then maybe not (and we don't know if it did get selected or not). If so then try to make another ssl client certificate and place it in user store.

Comment: Then maybe IIS does not trust CA that issued your client cert. What version of IIS do you have?

Comment: IIS 7.5. Looks like, yes... However, the server certificate which is also in place (and works) uses the same CA.

Comment: When you disable require client certificate (set it to ignore) then how does the page show? Is there a red `Continue to this website (not recommended).`?

Comment: What version of IIS is it? In IIS 6 there was an option to set a trusted CA list. Maybe your CA is not configured in this list.

Comment: Version 7.5. Don't know how to configure this list. Thought it's in as soon as a CA is in trusted store...

Comment: It was abandoned after IIS 6 and can not be set anymore. Now it depends on certificate store and trust all root CAs that are there. When you open details of client certificate do you see whole certificate path? What other extensions are in client cert? Try to make one using [Xca](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/) and compare differences.

Comment: Yes, I see the whole path (just the CA which is parent). Extensions: Enhanced Key Usage (Client Auth) and Authority Key Identifier. I'll check using Xca.

Comment: it's the same if I use Xca certificates :-(

Comment: It is weird. The only thing left that I would like to try is to take it to different computer/VM. That way we can check if your computer is messed up or there is some error in the issued certificates. I hope that only one path proves to be faulty :)